# Css IE6IE7/IE8 hover problem

Tags: css, cross-browser

I added this bit of code for the input button used by.net  for hover, the hover effect works fine on Firefox but does not work in any o the IEs

how can i make it work in IEs

```
#form-container input.prev_btn{
  display: block;
  background:none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  text-decoration:none;
  border:medium none;
  color:#5B522F;
  font-size:18px;
  left:285px;position:relative;
  text-transform:uppercase;top:34px;width:400px;
}
#form-container input.prev_btn:hover {
  background:none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  text-decoration:none;
  border:medium none;
  color:red;
  font-size:18px;
  left:285px;
  position:relative;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  top:34px;
  width:400px;
}



<input type="submit" class="prev_btn" id="btnPreview" value="create e-card" name="btnPreview">
```

Comment: I formatted your CSS. For the sake of a good question, please remove the non-relevant parts. You can test ":hover" at quirks mode: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/hover.html -- it works in IE8 here. Check the browser "mode" it is being run in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test ":hover" at quirks mode: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/hover.html -- it works in IE8 here. Check the browser "mode" it is being run in.

E.g. in "quirks mode", it all goes down-hill: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not doing much HTML programming myself, but I googled a bit, and IE does not support hovering the way you're trying to go it. I found the following webpage:
http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/6906.htm
which appears to give a solution to it. You can google for "HTC file", and "HTC file example" and the first hit on each search seems to give you essentially what you wanted.

Comment: IE8 (at least, in normal mode) does support it just fine. (I don't have other versions to test, but you can try it yourself at: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/hover.html)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old one, but the solution to this might simply be to add a DOCTYPE to the HTML page (above the opening HTML tag)

```
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
```