# Is there any way I can make a :hover opacity cross browser?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, opacity

I'm trying to get this effect to work in IE8, but can't seem to find a good solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/aarhG/2/

Have any ideas?

I've tried adding:

```
.image {
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";}

.box:hover .image {
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";}
```

but that doesn't seem to work on hover...

Comment: I hope you have `.box:hover .image` on your actual code. Does your `.image` have a layout?

Comment: Oh yeah, I missed the dot here, I'm not sure I know what you mean when you ask if .image has a layout.

Comment: Do you have any css property set to it? If so, what?

Comment: overflow: hidden;
display: block;
position: relative; it looks a lot like the fiddle right under figure is an image.

Comment: Can you try to set `.min-width:0;` to that and see if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### if you don't have a correct doc-type

The problem will most likely be down to that `:hover` is not supported in IE8 outside of `a` tags when using certain doc-types.

- [Is :hover:after supported in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328734/is-hoverafter-supported-in-ie8)
- [Css IE6IE7/IE8 hover problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100720/css-ie6ie7-ie8-hover-problem)
- [Hover effects not working with IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269831/hover-effects-not-working-with-ie8)

Generally if I wanted a hover effect in an older browser I would use an `a` tag to wrap the element:

```
<a href="#"><img /></a>
```

And then target using the following:

```
a:hover img { opacity: 0.5; filter: Alpha(opacity=50); }
```

You'll probably find that it isn't the opacity causing the problem, if you switched to changing another css property onhover — say border — it still wouldn't work without using a `a` tag.

#### after a further look

It seems that your doctype is ok, so the above note is not the issue. However it does seem that you are utilising html5 tags, which will also cause you issues in IE8. A fix for this is as follows.

Older versions of Internet Explorer do not fully recognise the new html5 tags, however if you create a singular instance of the tags you wish to use in JavaScript, IE starts believing the tags are real. This is generally part of what a [html5.js](http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/) shim would do. It is also a good idea to make sure these new tags are displaying as block in your css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=UTF-8">
<title> Opacity IE8 </title>
<style>
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.container .box {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: Alpha(opacity=0);
}
.container:hover .box {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: Alpha(opacity=100);
}
</style> 
<script>
  document.createElement('figure');
  document.createElement('figcaption');
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <figure class="container">
    hover me
    <figcaption class="box">
      <ul class="list">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks, I also noticed another issue... I had opacity set to 1 instead of 100... duh, thanks again!

Comment: @user1493230 Ah no problem, heh. Yeah I've done that one a few times... it's almost impossible to spot the error when 0 to 1 opacity seems perfectly normal :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in my sites and I have never had any problems with any browser, including older versions of IE: `{ filter: Alpha(opacity=80); opacity: .8; -moz-opacity: .8; }`.